# NuGet Configuration File for Solution VS2015 (NuGet 3.4+)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package, projects-and-solutions, solution

Okay this might sound a duplicated question, but regarding my searches it is not.

I have been looking for a proper way to configure a specific nuget package source (url) in my solution that automatically generate everything (.nuget folder and/or nuget configuration files) contrained to the solution path.

I don't want to use APPDATA neither MACHINE.

I want to use only the solution directory for everything, so when another user from the repository fetches the solution it get's everything properly installed (including the nuget references on package folder).

I have been reading NuGet documentation and it seems, the way this can be achieved is not straightforward, because of NuGet different versions and so on...

Can someone provide a minimalistic guide to achieve this purpose?
Thank you for your help in advance!

---

**Updated Question:**

I notice that with NuGet Version 3.4+ I don't need the **.nuget folder anymore!**

**My question/problem is configuring the package source url by solution and not by machine/appdata**, this is because I am using a private package source url containing a feed of corporate libraries! thanks :)

**Details:**

I notice that **the Package Sources URL are being stored in the NuGet.config file at %APPDATA%\NuGet\NuGet.Config**.

How can I **properly configure this by solution**? so it easly maintained in a corporate business?

(I mean I don't need each user to configure the source on their machine)

---

### **From NuGet Documentation:**

"A **solution-specific NuGet.Config file** located within a .nuget folder in the solution. Settings in this file apply only to solution-wide packages and is supported only in **NuGet 3.3 and earlier**. **It is ignored for NuGet 3.4 and later**."

Does that mean I can't properly configure sources for each solution separately? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay so here are the steps to configure it by solution (tested and applied to **NuGet 3.4.4**):

1. Create/Open your solution.
2. If it's first time and you never configured your private nuget
   package source you should go in your VS2015 into Tools > NuGet
   Package Manager > Package Manager Settings

[image]

3. Fill the information required for a new package source as I describe
   in the image below.

[image]

4. Then your Machine (AppData) NuGet configuration file will be updated
   at the following location: **%APPDATA%\NuGet\NuGet.Config**

[image]

5. What you have to do next is copy this NuGet.Config file into your
   solution folder, like the image below!

[image]

**Then you will notice that the package source will still be there, even if you deleted it from the AppData Folder! (Just make sure your restart your visual studio)**

---

**NOTE:** If you keep the NuGet.Config file in your AppData the VS itself will concatenate the contents of the config file in AppData and the ones in your solution folder!

**NOTE2:** Now you just need to check-in into your Git Repository/TFS the file configuration file specified in solution folder and that's it!

Comment: This means that "A solution-specific NuGet.Config file located within a .nuget folder in the solution. Settings in this file apply only to solution-wide packages and is supported only in NuGet 3.3 and earlier. It is ignored for NuGet 3.4 and later." is completely wrong! thanx nuget doc for make me wasting my time!

Comment: @A77 It works for me on VS2017 15.5.5. No .nuget folder needed and no  `NuGet 3.3 and earlier` limitation.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the nuget references path in your project, in my Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 with NuGet Package Manager 3.5, the nuget references are reference from the nuget package folder that in solution folder.
[image]

When adding this solution to repository, please make sure entire solution has been added, include the packages folder in solution.

Then after another user get this solution on another machine, the packages folder also will be checked out and the solution could bed used on another machine directly.

I don't use the nuget packages in APPDATA and MACHINE in the whole process.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have been reading NuGet Introduction from another guide, and now I am better prepared to handle this. I notice that with NuGet Version 3.4+ I don't need the .nuget folder anymore! My question/problem is configuring the package source url by solution and not by machine/appdata, do you understand? because I am using a private package source url containing a feed of corporate libraries :) thank you!

Comment: I notice that the Package Sources URL are being stored in the NuGet.config file at %APPDATA%\NuGet\NuGet.Config . How can I properly configure this by solution ? so it easly maintained in a corporate business ? ( I mean I don't need each user to configure the source on their machine )

Answer (score 0):

For VS2017,

1. Create a folder `MyLocalPackages`
2. Put NuGet package files in it.
3. Create `NuGet.config` aside the sln file

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <configuration>
     <packageSources>
       <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
       <add key="Local Packages" value=".\MyLocalPackages" />
     </packageSources>
   </configuration>
   ```

Works for VS2017 15.5.5.

Result: [image]